# Sql Query help for filtering data from another table based on result of first query

Tags: sql, database

I have a table that has created time and modified time for each ID

Now I want to use the modified time of each id that I get and find out last 1 year data for each id from the date of ‘modified/updated time’ that is in a different Table

All the IDs have different modified time. How can I do that in SQL?

| ID | Created Time | Modified Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | 01-01-2019 | 17-07-2022 |

| ID | Last 7 days | Last 30 days | Updated Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | 0 | 0 | 19-08-2022 |
| 23 | 0 | 0 | 18-08-2022 |
| . | . | . | . |
| . | . | . | . |
| . | . | . | . |
| . | . | . | . |
| 23 | 5 | 45 | 17-07-2022 |

Now I don’t want the first x rows as that is useless. I want data from 17-07-2022 and before.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried? Can you share your table structure?

Comment: I have a table that has columns “ID”, “Created Time”, “Modified Time”.  And I have another table that has “ID”, “Last 7 days data”, “Last 30 days data”, “Last 60 days data”, “Date” but this date is updated daily as the table is updated daily. I want to use the “modified date” that I get from my first query to find “Last 7 days data”, “Last 30 days data”, “Last 60 days data” from that “modified date” for Each ID. Does this makes sense?

Comment: Add some sample table data, until you add table data and structure , nobody help you.

Comment: @Kevin is the new edited summary helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?

```
select b.*
from tableA a JOIN tableB b on a.id = b.id
where b.updated_time between DATEADD(year, -1, a.Modified_time) and a.Modified_time
```

[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ce2c3117c7a9637c84fbf58aec6da9da)